# Excel VBA comparing two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I'm trying to create a macro which compares two Excel files. The only column both Excel files have in common is "`eRequest ID`". The goal is to display any records that DO NOT have an "`eRequest ID`" in both files.

For example, if record 1 is only found in one of the two files, it has to be displayed. The only situation where records are not displayed is if the "`eRequest ID`" is found in both files.

On a side note.. I recorded a simple macro to filter out some fields... I have to add in this part into the final macro as well.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2").Range. _
    AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("90 BIZ - Deferred", _
    "91 GTO - Deferred", "92 BIZ - Dropped", "94 GTO - Duplicate"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2").Range. _
    AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Core Banking"
```

Comment: Just to be clear.. the records in both files contains different data. The only thing linking them is the "eRequest ID" column.. it's like a primary key in SQL terms. Hope this helps!

Comment: How many records are there in each file?

Comment: -Tim Williams around 100. Does it matter though?? I need to make a macro which compares two excel files actually.. not just these SPECIFIC TWO. Like i need a macro which can be run with other similar excel files as well.

Comment: Number of records matters because for large files certain approaches will perform poorly,taking a long time to complete.  Smaller datasets can use a simpler approach.

Comment: - Tim Williams ah i see... the files i have to deal with generally comes in 100-300 records though. Do you know how to solve this?? Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Is there only a single table in each of the files?  It might help to describe your data in more detail - how many columns etc

Comment: -Tim Williams Yes there is only one table in each files. For the columns it can range from 10-30, it really depends.

Answer (score 0):

My brief answer: you'll need to build an array of each of your workbooks' unique IDs, and then filter vis-a-vis the array of the other workbook.
The remaining records will not be matching.

Working prototype:

```
Sub vkbthjgljskbr()
Dim wb(1) As Workbook, ws(1) As Worksheet, LastRow(1) As Long, FldCounter(1) As Long, _
ListObj(1) As String, FilterList() As String, OutputList() As String, x As Long, FilterArr() As String, RowNum() As Long
Set wb(0) = Workbooks("temp1")                'defining workbooks
    Set wb(1) = Workbooks("temp2")
Set ws(0) = wb(0).Worksheets("Munka1")        'worksheets
    Set ws(1) = wb(1).Worksheets("Munka1")
FldCounter(0) = 2                             'Fields (if your tables do not start at A1 you may need to create another counter)
    FldCounter(1) = 4
ListObj(0) = "Táblázat1"                      'Names of the list objects, actually you could define them as objects too
    ListObj(1) = "Táblázat1"
For j = 0 To 1                                'grabs the index last row of the worksheet
    LastRow(j) = ws(j).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Next

For j = 0 To 1 'removes filters
    If ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).ShowAutoFilter Then
        ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.AutoFilter
    End If
Next

UltLastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRow(0), LastRow(1)) - 1 'outputs the largest of lastrow indices - 1 to show index 0 is valid
    ReDim FilterList(UltLastRow, 1)  'initial filterlist
    ReDim OutputList(UltLastRow, 1)  'complementer list
    ReDim RowNum(UltLastRow, 1)
    ReDim FilterArr(UltLastRow)

For j = 0 To 1 'creates your initial filter lists
    x = 0
    For i = 2 To LastRow(j) 'assuming your table starts at A1
        FilterList(x, j) = ws(j).Cells(i, FldCounter(j)).Value2
        x = x + 1
    Next
Next

For j = 0 To 1 'applies initial filters
    Erase FilterArr
    ReDim FilterArr(UltLastRow)
    For x = 0 To UltLastRow 'not quite elegant way to slice array
        FilterArr(x) = FilterList(x, 1 - j)
    Next
    ReDim Preserve FilterArr(UltLastRow)
    ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.AutoFilter Field:=FldCounter(j), Criteria1:=FilterArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Next

For j = 0 To 1 'grabs hidden (non-matching) values
    x = 0
    Erase FilterArr
    ReDim FilterArr(UltLastRow)
    For i = 2 To LastRow(j) 'assuming your table starts at A1
        If ws(j).Rows("" & i).Hidden Then
            FilterArr(x) = ws(j).Cells(i, FldCounter(j)).Value2
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
    If ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).ShowAutoFilter Then 'removes filters
        ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.AutoFilter
    End If
    ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.AutoFilter Field:=FldCounter(j), Criteria1:=FilterArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'applies complementer filter
Next
End Sub
```

Now it works on my sample workbooks.

Comment: Hint: the remaining items will have the hidden property.

Comment: Sorry i actually dont really get what you mean... I'm a total begginer at VBA. I found this link though it compares every cell, [link](http://www.familycomputerclub.com/compare-two-excel-worksheets.html) The difference is that I only want to display the row of records that are not found in BOTH files, not EITHER OF THEM. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Excel is not good at listing complementers, don't ask me why. You can list out the complementer set and reimplement the filter with that list.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at with the array part... but my question is how do I do it in codes??

Comment: I'd been having a slow day at work but now having requests, will upload the non-owrking prototype now and return when I have time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.. but i'm really having lots of trouble with this. I'm really thankful for your help!

Comment: Btw.. when defining the first workbook, i changed it to "D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\MasterInventory.xlsm" but somehow i get a runtime error 9, subscript out of range. Do you know why??

Comment: You either choose it from the open ones by simple name or open a new one with the path definition of yours and then use `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` to do the trick. There are probably easier solutions too.

Comment: There you go, finally working for me. Tomorrow I might make it work even for tables not located at A1.

Comment: Hmm, for the `ListObj(0) = "Táblázat1" ` line, what am i supposed to change it to? Or is it supposed to remain like this? Really thankful for your help!

Comment: That one is going to be "Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2" in your case. It's a table.

Comment: On this line `Set ws(0) = wb(0).Worksheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")` I'm getting an error where "Method or data member is not found"

Comment: That should be the worksheet's name where the list object is located, not the listobject name. I recommend double clicking the worksheet name tab and copying the text from there.

Comment: Yes, sorry but what is wb(0) and wb(1)? Are they the workbooks? Am i supposed to change them according to my workbooks' names?

Comment: Yes, those are the two workbooks of your choice. Make sure the worksheets are matching the workbooks and the listobjects (tables) match the worksheets(the index [0 or 1] is the same).

Comment: Really sorry to trouble you.. but i don't really understand what you mean.. Would it help if I gave you my Workbooks and Table names? It's "Master Inventory.xlsm" and "Release Dev Status.xlsx".
For the tables, its "Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2" and "Table_JULY15Release_Dev_status__2".
Really hope you can help me out.. This has been troubling me for quite a while now.. Appreciate all the help you've been giving so far!

Comment: `wb(0) = "Master Inventory" > ws(0) = ? > ListObj(0) = "Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2"` - `wb(1) = "Release Dev Status" > ws(0) = ? > ListObj(0) = "Table_JULY15Release_Dev_status__2"`

Answer (score 0):

Assumes source workbooks are open and listobjects are on the first sheet.  Adjust workbook names and sheet indexes/names to suit:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim lst1 As ListObject, lst2 As ListObject
Dim c1 As ListColumn, c2 As ListColumn
Dim rngDest As Range

    Set lst1 = Workbooks("WkBk A.xlsx").Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
    Set lst2 = Workbooks("WkBk B.xlsx").Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)

    Set c1 = lst1.ListColumns("eRequest ID")
    Set c2 = lst2.ListColumns("eRequest ID")

    Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    CopyIfNotMatched c1, c2, rngDest
    CopyIfNotMatched c2, c1, rngDest

End Sub

Sub CopyIfNotMatched(c1 As ListColumn, c2 As ListColumn, rngDest As Range)
    Dim c As Range, f As Range

    For Each c In c1.DataBodyRange.Cells
        Set f = c2.DataBodyRange.Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, _
                    c1.Parent.DataBodyRange).Copy rngDest
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: -Tim Williams, Hi Tim, appreciate your help but I'm having a run-time error 9, subscribt out of range error on line `Set lst1 = Workbooks("D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\Master Inventory2.xlsm").Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)`
How do i solve this?

Comment: Never mind that.. I solved it but when i run your code, nothing is happening?? I need another workbook to be opened where the records that do not have an **eRequest ID** in both files would be copied over.

Comment: I added and changed the code a little.. `Set wkb = Workbooks.Add NewBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\Result.xlsx") Set rngDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")` When i run the code, the new workbook **Result.xlsx** part is working fine, however nothing is being copied over.. As usual, appreciate any help given!

Comment: The code I posted works for me.  It's difficult to say why your edited version isn't giving the results you expect.  I can take a look if you can share your files, otherwise there's not much I can do.