# Excel VBA Compare Three Excel List and Findout All Common Parts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a three excel files `(A, B and C)`. And I have to compare `A` list to other lists to find if `B` and `C` list have same parts than `A`. Then have a separate list of parts that can be found list `A` and `(B or C)`. Also it would be good if in the list have info Which one list `(b or C)` part have found. 
In the lists column 1 is ID number and column 2 is part name.

Now I have tried following code:

```
Sub lookup()
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("A1:B" & TotalRows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("Sheet3").Select

For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Search for the value on sheet2
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1), LookAt:=xlWhole)
    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But it's not very good for me. Because now I have to copy B and C list in sheet 2 and then this code copies all A list to sheet 3 and next column what are common with sheet2.

And do I have to say there are thousands of parts.
Even easy way to comparing B to A list would be good.

So I really need your help.

Comment: If your data are in data tables I can help you by refering to my previous [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30024469/3819867). The list objects are subsets of worksheets and worksheets are subsets of workbooks. You need to define them all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Query to the rescue (**Data->From Other Sources->Microsoft Query**).

### **Example for comparing Sheets A and B**

**Step 1**: Add a Row Number column to sheets A and B

**Step 2**: Create the query:

```
SELECT SheetA.A, SheetB.B FROM [SheetA$] as SheetA,
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SheetB$] as SheetB ON SheetA.A = SheetB.B
```

### **What if they are in different files?**

```
SELECT SheetA.A, SheetB.B FROM `C:\FileA.xlsx`.`SheetA$` as SheetA,
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\FileA.xlsx`.`SheetA$` as SheetB ON SheetA.A = SheetB.B
```

As always I recommend using my AddIn to create the queries: [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/) or use the Wizard (Data->From Other Sources->Microsoft Query).